# Calculating values by iterating through 2 nested lists at the same time

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'm trying to traverse a list in Python and get the average. For example,

```
A = [[3,4,6], [7,9,13], 'New York Jets']
```

- A[0] represents the wins
- A[1] represents the losses
- A[2] is the team

**I want to do: (3/10) + (4/13) + (6/19)**

basically, wins/(wins+losses). This is what I tried:

```
wins = A[0]
losses = A[1]

total = 0.0
for w,l in zip(wins, losses):
    total += float(w/(w+l))
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me the wrong answer

Comment: Shouldn't that be `4/13` instead of `4/11`?

Comment: Yes, it should be '4/13'

Comment: I'd suggest using a dictionary as a better container, and format it like such `{'New York Jets': {'wins': [3, 4, 6], 'losses': [7, 9, 13]}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w / (w + l)` is already an integer, so passing it into `float` won't help.

Either make one of them a float:

```
float(w) / (w + 1)
```

Or import the Python 3's division at the top of your script, where dividing two integers results in a float:

```
from __future__ import division
```

---

You could do something like:

```
averages = []

for wins, losses, team in teams:
    average = sum(win / float(win + loss) for win, loss in zip(wins, losses))

    averages.append(average)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a list of teams? i.e. teams = [[5,4,2],[7,2,1], 'Jets'], [[7,3,5],[2,8,4], 'Lions'], [[3,6,2],[8,2,4], 'Jaguars']]. Then I can get the Average for each team at once

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A = [[3,4,6], [7,9,13], 'New York Jets']
>>> [float(wins)/(wins+losses) for wins, losses in zip(*A[:2])]
[0.3, 0.3076923076923077, 0.3157894736842105]
>>> sum(float(wins)/(wins+losses) for wins, losses in zip(*A[:2]))
0.9234817813765183
```